# jqGrid casting data to a String before sort

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to sort a list of orders based on total money spent on the purchase. The list looks like this (extra fields omitted for clarity):

```
[
  {products:[
    {name: 'foo',price:2.53},
    {name: 'bar',price:5.74}
  ]},
  {products:[
    {name: 'baz',price:6.74},
    {name: 'quux', price:7.68}
  ]}
]
```

The column definition in question looks like this (with `sumPricesOf` taking an array similar to the above and returning the total spent):

```
{
    name: 'products',
    label: 'Total spent',
    index: 'products',
    formatter: function(d){return '$'+sumPricesOf(d.products)},
    sorttype: 'function',
    sortfunc: function(a,b){
      return sumPricesOf(a.products) - sumPricesOf(b.products);
    }
}
```

However, if I use `console.log(a,b)` in the `sortfunc`, when it gets called `a` and `b` are getting passed as strings! The arguments get passed as `[object Object],[object Object]`.

Why can't jqGrid just give me back the data that I passed it?

Answer (score 0):

Strong recomend use **sorttype: float** option in [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) array.

Comment: This doesn't really answer it... I'm asking why the `sortfunc` is getting useless string forms of my arguments instead of the arguments themselves.